# Applying LayoutTransform only to parent but not to any particular child

Tags: c#, wpf

**MainWindow.XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPFApp.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Name="myMainWindow"
            Title="MainWindow" Width="200" Height="250">
        <Grid Name="MainGrid" SizeChanged="MainGrid_SizeChanged">
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ApplicationScaleTransform"
                            CenterX="0"
                            CenterY="0"
                            ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=myMainWindow, Path=ScaleValue}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=myMainWindow, Path=ScaleValue}" />
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="150">
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Hello World" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Content="Button" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="myButton"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </Window>
```

**Main Window CodeBehind:**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region ScaleValue Depdency Property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ScaleValue", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnScaleValueChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(OnCoerceScaleValue)));

        private static object OnCoerceScaleValue(DependencyObject o, object value)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = o as MainWindow;
            if (mainWindow != null)
                return mainWindow.OnCoerceScaleValue((double)value);
            else
                return value;
        }

        private static void OnScaleValueChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = o as MainWindow;
            if (mainWindow != null)
                mainWindow.OnScaleValueChanged((double)e.OldValue, (double)e.NewValue);
        }

        protected virtual double OnCoerceScaleValue(double value)
        {
            if (double.IsNaN(value))
                return 1.0f;

            value = Math.Max(0.1, value);
            return value;
        }

        protected virtual void OnScaleValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
        {

        }

        public double ScaleValue
        {
            get
            {
                return (double)GetValue(ScaleValueProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ScaleValueProperty, value);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private void MainGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalculateScale();
        }

        private void CalculateScale()
        {
            double yScale = ActualHeight / 250f;
            double xScale = ActualWidth / 200f;
            double value = Math.Min(xScale, yScale);
            ScaleValue = (double)OnCoerceScaleValue(MainGrid, value);
        }
    }
```

I have this sample application. I am applying **LayoutTransform** on the MainGrid to scale application with the resize of window. How can i avoid my control **myButton** to apply that transform? I dont want that transform to apply on it.

Comment: Have a look at [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) what you are creating here seems like what the ViewBox already does but builtin in WPF.

Comment: No ViewBox does not scale it like i want. This solution is perfectly doing what i want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two options

1) Don't make it a child, instead only make it visually overlap, using a second grid for example.

2) Apply the inverse of the transformation to the children, this will negate the transformation, can be expensive but should do the trick.

```
<Button LayoutTransform="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=LayoutTransform.Inverse}"/>
```

personally i would use the first option.

Comment: I get 'System.Windows.Media.GeneralTransform' and 'System.Windows.Media.Transform'. How to work around it?